# How to find x intercept?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$y=(x-4)^3+1$

So, to find the X intercept. $0=(x-4)^3+1$
How to solve the equation $0=(x-4)^3+1$ ?
Please explain with steps.

Comment: Replace $x-4$ with $u$; solve $u^3+1=0$; replace $u$ with $x-4$.

Comment: Seeing as you posted 3 recent questions on finding $x$-intercepts, you probably need some practice at it. [Paul's Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/Graphing.aspx) has this. Basically, to find $x$-intercepts, you replace $y$ with $0$ and solve the equation for $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0=(x-4)^3+1\implies (x-4)^3=-1\implies x-4=-1\implies x=4-1=3$

Answer (score 0):

1. Solve $x^3 = -1$.
2. Put your equation into that form.

Answer (score 0):

$(x-4)^3 + 1^3 = ((x-4)+1)((x-4)^2 + 1 - (x-4)) = 0$
$\implies (x-3)(x^2+16 - 8x + 1 - x + 4) = 0$
$\implies (x-3)(x^2+21 - 9x) = 0$
$\implies (x-3)(x^2+21 - 9x) = 0$
$x = 3$ is the only real root since $(x^2 - 9x + 21)$ has complex roots.

Answer (score 0):

A quick calculation shows that $x_1=3$ is a (real) solution:

$$(x_1-4)^3+1=(-1)^3+1=-1+1=0.$$

This leaves us with the task of finding the two remaining, complex solutions. Using the knowledge that $x=3$ is a solution, we also know that $(x-3)$ is a "factor" of the cubic polynomial. Using [synthetic division](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/synthdiv.htm), we find that the cubic polynomial may be re-expressed as

$$(x-4)^3+1=x^3 -12x^2+48x-63 = (x-3)(x^2-9x+21)$$

The remaining two roots, then, must the solutions to the quadratic equation $$x^2-9x+21=0.$$

From the basic equation for roots of a quadratic equation, we find

$$x_{2,3} =\frac{9}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i,$$

where, as usual, $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

Summing up, the cubic equation has one real and two complex conjugate solutions.